# What happens when point of solution is not 0 in Frobenius method?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, frobenius-method

I have been solving Frobenius method problems. However it always has been a point of solution equal to 0 (x = 0). What happens when there's a given problem such as below and it's point of solution say x = 2?

$ x(x-1)y^{''}+(x-2)y^{'}-y = 0 $

Also some examples wherein point of solution (x = 0) is a singular point: [LINK](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Differential_Equations/Book%3A_Differential_Equations_for_Engineers_(Lebl)/7%3A_Power_series_methods/7.3%3A_Singular_Points_and_the_Method_of_Frobenius).

**EDIT:**

May I add a question, how do get now the singular points?

Comment: change variable $z=x-2$

Comment: If the leading coefficient is not zero in the expansion point, then the expansion you get is a regular power series.